# tikz automata: making the label positioning of a transition independent from the fact that a state is accepting or not

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, labels

While writing some code that generates TikZ code for displaying an automaton, I encounter the following issue: with the same label annotation, namely 'edge[bend angle=18,bend right] node[below=0,sloped]', the position of the label depends on the fact that some source/destination state is accepting or not: on the next figure, case b is wrongly positioned: is there a way to have some uniform command for positioning the label correctly, no matter whether the source/destination states are accepting or not ?
Is it possible that this is a bug in TikZ (other positioning that I tried out were not sensitive to the fact that the source/destination states were accepting or not).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} \usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,semithick]

\begin{scope}
\node[state] (1a) at (1cm,1cm) {1a};
\node[state] (2a) at (1cm,3cm) {2a};
\path
(1a) edge[bend angle=18,bend right] node[below=0,sloped] {$=$} (2a);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=2cm]
\node[state,accepting] (1b) at (1cm,1cm) {1b};
\node[state]           (2b) at (1cm,3cm) {2b};
\path
(1b) edge[bend angle=18,bend right] node[below=0,sloped] {$=$} (2b);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=4cm]
\node[state]           (1c) at (1cm,1cm) {1c};
\node[state,accepting] (2c) at (1cm,3cm) {2c};
\path
(1c) edge[bend angle=18,bend right] node[below=0,sloped] {$=$} (2c);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=6cm]
\node[state,accepting] (1d) at (1cm,1cm) {1d};
\node[state,accepting] (2d) at (1cm,3cm) {2d};
\path
(1d) edge[bend angle=18,bend right] node[below=0,sloped] {$=$} (2d);
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why this happens is that for sloped paths Ti*k*Z tries to intelligently interpret keys like `above` and so on. To switch this off, you can use the `allow upside down` key.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,semithick,
    allow upside down]

\begin{scope}
\node[state] (1a) at (1cm,1cm) {1a};
\node[state] (2a) at (1cm,3cm) {2a};
\path
(1a) edge[bend angle=18,bend right] node[below=0,sloped] {$=$} (2a);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=2cm]
\node[state,accepting] (1b) at (1cm,1cm) {1b};
\node[state]           (2b) at (1cm,3cm) {2b};
\path
(1b) edge[bend angle=18,bend right] node[below=0,sloped] {$=$} (2b);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=4cm]
\node[state]           (1c) at (1cm,1cm) {1c};
\node[state,accepting] (2c) at (1cm,3cm) {2c};
\path
(1c) edge[bend angle=18,bend right] node[below=0,sloped] {$=$} (2c);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=6cm]
\node[state,accepting] (1d) at (1cm,1cm) {1d};
\node[state,accepting] (2d) at (1cm,3cm) {2d};
\path
(1d) edge[bend angle=18,bend right] node[below=0,sloped] {$=$} (2d);
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This is off-topic, but in order to shorten your code you could use a loop.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,automata}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=Stealth,shorten >=1pt,auto,semithick]
\foreach \X [count=\Y] in {a,...,d}
{
 \ifodd\Y
  \path  (2*\Y,1)  node[state]  (1\X) {1\X};
 \else 
  \path  (2*\Y,1)  node[state,accepting]  (1\X) {1\X};
 \fi
 \ifnum\Y<3
  \path   (2*\Y,3) node[state](2\X) {2\X};
 \else
  \path   (2*\Y,3) node[state,accepting](2\X) {2\X};
 \fi
 \path
 (1\X) edge[bend angle=18,bend right] node[below=0,sloped,
 allow upside down] {$=$} (2\X);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Whether or not these ways of shortening codes make sense always depends on what one ultimately has in mind.

Comment: Since my TikZ code is generated by a program the question of shortening TikZ code is not so important to me (but if an can avoid case analysis whether some states are accepting or not, this makes my code generator a bit simpler).

Comment: The upside down key is also dependent of whether the source/destination are accepting or not for other label annotation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, why this happen, however, using `quotes` library, set `auto=right` and write `edge ["$=$"]` solve your problem. Of course, you need to define arrows and edges quotes accordingly (see MWE below). With using TikZ library `chains` make the code shorter:

```
    \begin{scope}[nodes={state, on chain}]
\node (s11)                 {1a};
\node (s12)                 {1b};
\node (s13) [accepting]     {1c};
\node (s14) [accepting]     {1d};
%
\node (s21) [above=of s11]  {2a};
\node (s22) [accepting]     {2b};
\node (s23)                 {1c};
\node (s24) [accepting]     {1d};
    \end{scope}
    \foreach \i in {1,...,4}
{
\path   (s1\i) edge["$=$"] (s2\i);
}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]